# How can I use a string to call an enum in swift

Tags: swift, string, enums

I have an enum with a bunch of data, and there is a request from the server that returns a string - the key to this enum.

How do I dynamically call the value of this enum

```
public enum Solid: String{
     case val1 = "value1"
     case val2 = "value2"
     …
}

let serverResponce : String = "val1"

let getValFromEnum = Solid.serverResponce
```

And of course on the last line there is an error that Solid enum has no member 'serverResponce'

How can I solve this point?

Comment: I think you're looking for `Solid(rawValue: serverResponse)`

Comment: @jnpdx no, I need find enum value and I have only enum key as String

Comment: I don't know what that means